# Unable to Identify VL805 device

Tags: usb, usb-device, pcie, usb-host, pci

I have designed a PCIE to USB3 converter device that is based to VIA LABS [VL805](https://www.via-labs.com/product_show.php?id=48)  Q6 Chip.

My problem that I can't recognize the VL805 chip in Linux, using the command "lspci":
[image]

here is the schematic for the design [VL805](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y7i9rangqkjalhf/FT.ED-USB3PCIV4.pdf?dl=0). Wherever there is the world "NEW" its something that doesn't exist in the current board version and I want to make a revision for it.

on the first version of the board, I mistakenly connected TX of the PCI (from CPU) to the TX of the device, and also connected the RX's together. then I made an ECO for several boards in order to see if this can solve the problem before sending a request for board revision.
Unfortunately, this didn't solve the problem. (in the current PDF the TX signals are connected to RX signals in the right way, as they should be)

Notes:

- There is an External SPI flash that should include a firmware that VIA labs sent me. I already flashed it with the firmware on previous board but that didn't help. on the current validation boards I didn't flash this SPI. I think that at least I should be able to recognize the device even before it having firmware.
- all the voltages for the device are provided (checked in DVM), but I didn't check if the power up sequence is in the right order that VIA LABS suggested in their design notes:
  [image]

Questions:

1. Is this SPI critical for the Device Identification process?
2. could the power up sequence be the cause of the reason? they didn't provide any specification about the time difference between the different signals.
3. I didn't place series capacitors to the TX pin outputs as in the picture:
   [image], could this be really the source of the
   problem?

Update: after replacing the ECO for the TX and RX wires fix with thinner wires and adding 100nf series capacitors to the VL805 pins, and externally flashing the SPI, the chip was recognized and functioned correctly. the PCIE to USB3 device works and is in a good shape. right now I'm doing validation tests.

Comment: Why do you expect the SPI Flash is not critical? It holds the fimrware for the chip. Possibly the PCIe VID/PID as well. At least you should mount the SPI and program it before further testing. You could also ask chip vendor directly to know for sure.

Comment: I got the Impression from my experienced colleges that at least I should be able to recognize the device even before flashing any firmware. I will try to flash the firmware again, after I added the series capacitors to the Chip's TX pins.

Comment: @Xhero39: How did you externally flash the VL805's SPI flash memory? I'm attempting to use this chip too.

Comment: @boardbite, you can freely see my schematic. I used DEDIPROG Programmer and got the Fimrware required from VIALABS. I'm not sure I can share it.